# How to show custom login validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

How to show custom validation in a login page. I have a type of users. If specific user type does not login show errors message. I have a login form in which user with specific type is allowed to log in. For example, if `subscriber` type are allowed to log in. If another user of type `user` tries to login it should show an error message saying only subscribers are allowed to log in.

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'type' => new TypeRule
    ]);
}
```

**TypeRule**

```php
class TypeRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value === 'subscriber' || $value === 'admin';
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return ':attribute subsciber is allowed to login';
    }
}
```

Currently, rules are not validated to required. No error messages show if email or password is not entered.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question straight forward, I would first take a look at your first validation rule. Without seeing your form, I am going to assume you have a field called `username`. What you are doing currently is populating the value of `username` instead of supplying the name of the field. Try changing your request to this:

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'type' => new TypeRule
    ]);
}
```

To dive a little bit deeper, is the field `type` a hidden field being passed on the form? If so, this presents a potential security flaw. I could easily open the Dev Tools and switch the type field to be whatever I wanted. I would consider approaching this by instead making a middleware over the protected routes. In this middleware, you could check the user's type - instead of including it in your validation

First, remove the type from your validation:

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Then, create a new middleware by running the following command:

```
$ php artisan make:middleware IsSubscriber
```

Now, open the file created at `app/Http/Middleware/IsSubscriber.php` and add a check to see if the current authenticated user is of the type `subscriber`

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->type !== 'subscriber') {
            return abort(403, 'The user is not a subscriber, therefore cannot log in.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you will need to register the middleware in your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'subscriber' => App\Http\Middleware\IsSubscriber::class,
];
```

And then finally, add the middleware to your routes `web.php` file - I am going to assume some simple routes:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['subscriber']], function(){

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    });

});
```

Don't forget to run:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan optimize:clear
```